# MYSQL Order By Sum of Columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Any idea on how to order the results of a MYSQL query by the sum of two columns rather than by a single column?

```
Select * FROM table ORDER BY (col1+col2) desc
```

I know that won't work., but I hope it conveys what I want to do fairly well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why not try before concluding it doesn't work?  In point of fact, it does.

Comment: Will storing the sum(col1 +col2) in col3 and index on it, makes the query fast??

Comment: @user2681045, I doubt it will make the query in the question faster.  If you change it to `ORDER BY col3` and have the proper index, maybe.  But that's at the cost of denormalizing your table.

Comment: he didn't know how close to succeeding he was before giving up and posting a question.

Comment: This doesn't work either if that sum is negative, since the result in that sum should be an unsigned bigint

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have a table named '**Students**'

[image]

Now you want to know the total marks scored by each student.
So, type the following query

```
SELECT Name, S1, S2, SUM(S1+S2) AS TOTAL
FROM Students
GROUP BY Name, S1, S2
ORDER BY Total;
```

You will get the following result.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think you should be able to do

```
SELECT *, col1+col2 as mysum ORDER BY mysum
```

Which is essentially the same as you already have

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this is NOT working in some cases.
Check if some value is `NULL`

```
Select * FROM table ORDER BY (IFNULL(col1,0)+IFNULL(col2,0)) desc
```

Comment: Thank you, I was having this issue and couldn't quite figure out why :) Odd that this is not the default behavior, imho

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote should work just fine, you can have any expression in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: It does not work for me, I don't think you can have an expression on the ORDER BY clause