# MySQL select HOTTEST (most upvoted in shortest time)

Tags: mysql

For a long time I have been trying to figure out how to make `Hottest Posts`

What I want to achieve : `ORDER BY MOST UPVOTED IN LESS TIME`

For example I got 4 posts:

```
ID         UPVOTES(Total)        UPVOTES(Weekly)               DATE
1             50                       50                    01.09.2017
2             421                      6                     25.07.2017
3             71                       50                    13.08.2017
4             111                      37                    15.08.2017
```

And It would need to order like `1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2`

> My Goal is to get UPVOTES(Weekly) - > I Don't know how to calculate
>   it. I just made it here, to better explain what I want to achieve.

I have got 2 database tables `fun_posts` and `fun_post_upvotes`
[image: fun_posts]

[image: fun_post_upvotes]

I was trying to achieve it like this, but it didn't work, it just ordered by id or ordered by upvotes

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare=("SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  
fun_post_upvotes WHERE image_id=fun_posts.id GROUP BY image_id) FROM fun_posts 
ORDER BY fun_posts.id DESC, fun_posts.upvotes DESC");
```

Comment: Just a little reminder before: shouldnt your order be like 3 -> 1 -> 4 -> 2. Shouldnt be the total upvotes be the 2nd comparator if they have the same amount of weekly updates?

Comment: So `UPVOTES(Weekly)` is an average you calculated somehow? Or is that in relation to the specific week of the date?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @phaen No 1 - > 3 -> 4 -> 2 , becouse post, with ID '1' is newest.

Comment: @CBroe I don't have UPVOTES(Weekly) Just made this to explain what I want to do, I don't even know how to calculate it.

Comment: Don't you need a date column on the table `fun_post_upvotes` in order to know which upvotes were created in the last 7 days ?

Comment: Please provide a SQL dump off both tables. And post de create table statements and insert statements instead of those images... you will get more help this way... phpmyadmin support a very easy to use export function.

Answer (score -1):

This is working a part of it.

```
SELECT fun_posts_upvotes.image_ID, COUNT(image_ID) as 'Upvotes' FROM fun_posts_upvotes GROUP BY fun_posts_upvotes.image_ID ORDER BY Upvotes DESC;
```

Just try it and add the Date part. ;-) you can ask again if you tried some :P

Comment: Sorry, my mistake(Didn't mentioned it in topic) But if you checked out database table image, you would see, that I don't have any UPVOTES(Weekly), I just made it here, to better explain what I want to achieve. My goal is to get that UPVOTES(Weekly), but I don't know how to calculate it

Comment: ahh, ok sorry for that. Well ill have a look into it. So you want to calculate how many upvotes a post got by summing up its appearance in fun posts upvotes by imageid, userid

Comment: I want to calculate how much upvotes posts have got in week. (Monday-Monday/Tuesday-Tusday/) Like last 7 days from today. And then order by weekly upvotes count.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem correctly you should quite easily be able to apply the following to your problem:

[MYSQL Order By Sum of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059138/mysql-order-by-sum-of-columns)

[Order By Sum of Two Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309203/order-by-sum-of-two-fields)

```
CREATE TABLE `tb1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`up` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Down` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SELECT `Name`, (`tb1`.`up`/  DATEDIFF(NOW(),`tb1`.`Date` )) as `heat`
FROM `tb1` 
ORDER BY (`tb1`.`up`/  DATEDIFF(`tb1`.`Date`, NOW())) ASC
```

This should illustrate my point

Comment: please explain why this doesnt help, or where you need clarification

Comment: @TobySpeight Working on an improvement

Answer (score -2):

I think adding to your query:

```
ORDER BY UPVOTES(Weekly) DESC
```

would work for your issue.

Comment: @LSelter Don't know who downvoted. But if you checked out database table image, you would see, that I don't have any UPVOTES(Weekly), I just made it here, to better explain what I want to achieve. My goal is to get that UPVOTES(Weekly), but I don't know how to calculate it.